# Tried to change the background color and text color in Flutter toast. But its not working properly

Tags: flutter, validation, dart, authentication, toast

While trying to change the background color and text color of toast message in flutter, the changes are not reflecting.

Help me with the solution.

```
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
              msg: text,
              toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
              gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
              timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 16.0
          );
```

[image]

Comment: Can you try with `flutter clean` and restart the app.

Answer (score 1):

```
Fluttertoast.showToast(
    msg: "This is Center Short Toast",
    toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
    gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
    timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    textColor: Colors.white,
    fontSize: 16.0
);
```

If this didn't work run flutter clean and restart the app

Comment: Before use this must need to add [fluttertoat](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast) dependency

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. It seems to be a problem with android 11. The code is working in android 10. [More infos here](https://githubmate.com/repo/ponnamkarthik/FlutterToast/issues/340).

What worked for me is using the
[toast with buildcontext](https://github.com/ponnamkarthik/FlutterToast#toast-with-buildcontext). You can create your own child and render it as the toast.

Answer (score 1):

add below lines...

```
webPosition: "center",
webBgColor: "linear-gradient(to right, #dc1c13, #dc1c13)",
```

for web you have to give webBgColor...

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. Using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast) dependency

Your `FlutterTost` Widget.

```
Fluttertoast.showToast(
  msg: "Invalid Username or Password",
  toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
  gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
  timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,       
);
```

Your result blue color Screen-> [image: Image 1]

Your result green color Screen->[image]